# Python pandas apply on more columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

How can I generate more columns in a dataframe using apply with more columns? My df is:

```
    A   B   C
0  11  21  31
1  12  22  31
```

If I want to generate only one column that works perfectly:

```
df['new_1']=df[['A','C','B']].apply(lambda x: x[1]/2, axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
    A   B   C  new_1
0  11  21  31   15.5
1  12  22  32   16.0
```

But what about if I want to generate more than one column?
This works perfectly:

```
df[['new_1','new_2']]=df[['A','C']].apply(lambda x: [x[1]/2,x[1]*2], axis=1)
```

The result is:

```
    A   B   C  new_1  new_2
0  11  21  31   15.5     62
1  12  22  32   16.0     64
```

But what if I want to use more than two columns at apply?

```
df[['new_1','new_2']]=df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda x: [x[1]/2,x[2]*2], axis=1)
```

I get this error:

```
KeyError: "['new_1' 'new_2'] not in index"
```

Any help? I use Python 2.7 and pandas 0.15.2

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Series constructor within the apply usually does the trick:

```
In [11]: df[['new_1','new_2']] = df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[1]/2,x[2]*2]), axis=1)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
    A   B   C  new_1  new_2
0  11  21  31     10     62
1  12  22  31     11     62
```

---

I see a different error without it (before assignment):

```
In [21]: df[['A','B','C']].apply(lambda x: [x[1]/2,x[2]*2], axis=1)
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (2, 2), indices imply (2, 3)
```

Comment: And what if I want to return with different types of elements? pd.Series([str(x[1]/2),x[2]*2]) returns with error :(

Comment: @ragesz that works for me with the above example, what version of pandas, what error? (Maybe worth asking a new question)

Comment: OK, My problem is that a pd.Series object can have only one data type. Of course it's not a problem. If all element in the Series is numeric then the data type can be float, but if one element is an object (str) in the series than the series type will be object. The pd.Dataframe.apply method or simply the pd.DataFrame will recognise if my new column values are all numeric and not object as the pd.Series says, so the column data type will be float and not object.

Comment: But what if I work with timestamps? I want to create a datetime (date) column and an object (name of day) column from the timestamp. At that case the pd.Series type will be datetime that is wrong because of the "name of the day" column. I can convert the datetime value to object than the pd.Series type will be objcet. But at datetimes the pd.DataFrame will not recognise if my first column's values are all datetimes but not objects so I have to manually change the data type to datetime.

Comment: Or I have to use two separate pd.DataFrame.apply - one for the datetime column and an other for the object column. I think two 'one-column-apply' method is worse than one 'two-column-apply' method in performance.

Comment: Sorry I meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask (it's better to format a new question and will get more attention). Saying that, usually you can get around this by setting the dtype=object i.e. `.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([x[1]/2,x[2]*2], dtype=object)`.

Comment: Thank you, it works well. And with this solution, the datetime (date) column will automatically converted into datetime64 type :)